# For loop is iterating a list without order in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate a file's lines. But for loop does not preserve the order. Actually it is not random, every time it follows same order, but not the correct order. And it sometimes goes to the same index multiple times. To able to show better, I added all the indices into a list.

```
numbers = [ ]
html_file = 'page.pwc'

with open(html_file, "r+") as f:
    html_text = f.readlines()
    for line in html_text:
        numbers.append(html_text.index(line))
        #time.sleep(1)
        
print(numbers)
```

And this is the output ( I will add image to show, as it's kinda huge to copy-paste here)

[image]

What could be the reason for this? Am I missing something simple? Could someone else try the same code and see if it is reproducible? For html file you can use this website's html: http://example.com/ .
It also gives the same result for me, but with different ordering.

Comment: That looks like you have repeated lines in the HTML - the first 8 lines are the same, so `html_text.index(line)` returns 0 for all of them; then the 9th etc. lines are different, and so on

Comment: Please read `list.index` docs. It always returns the index of the **first** element it finds

Comment: `list.index(x)` will return return zero-based index in the list of the **first** item whose value is equal to x. There are optional `start` and `end` params. What your goal is?

Comment: Also note that reading `html` file line by line does not make much sense.

Comment: I never thought about that. Seems it was a simple mistake. thanks for the comments and answer. I will accept the answer below. 

I'm just trying to delete a tag block with a specific class. I couldn't do this, so I was going for line match. @buran

Comment: you should look at `BeautifulSoup`  - [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: I checked but I could just see the examples which deletes all the tags with same name. I needed to delete just one block with a specific class name. @buran

Comment: use `PageElement.decompose()` or `Page.Element.replace_with()` methods. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose and https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with If you still need help - start new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
numbers = [ ]
html_file = 'page.pwc'

with open(html_file, "r+") as f:
    html_text = f.readlines()
    for idx, line in enumerate(html_text):
        numbers.append(idx)
        
print(numbers)
```

Comment: why not just `list(range(len(html_text)))`? I guess there is something else to OP question.